# How to get GUID of a specific desktop icon?

Tags: windows, registry, guid, windows-shell

I want to get a GUID from desktop icon to use it in registry (as shown in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543258/15218705). Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Icons on desktop don't all have a GUID. Only some of them (well known ones) have. Otherwise, icons are usually standard Windows shortcuts (.lnk files). What are you trying to do?

Comment: @SimonMourier I am trying to create something like Stardock Fences (I tried it out but it doesn't seem working as I wanted.) in C#.  I am pretty sure it creates another desktop and uses it to move icons from one to another, but it creates a lot of other issues, such as laggy widgets and incompatibility with Wallpaper Engine. I tried removing it with LVM_DELETEITEM message, it works but after I refresh the desktop it reappears. So I thought why not just get desktop icon's GUID and use it to hide when moving to a new window with listview.

Comment: From what I see, there's no other desktop. A .dll is hosted into Explorer, and so can draw custom "things" (groups) on the desktop. The desktop items are the same, but their position is changed using standard API: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Simon Mourier answered not every desktop icon has a GUID (Known ones https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3123-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-10-a.html)